# How to get and pass database table id of one row in two places in JSP?

Tags: java, database, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, servlets

I am getting ID from database in one place, here the code

```
<%
int id;
while(rsu.next()) {
    id = rsu.getInt(1);             
%>
<tr class="gradeA">
<td><%= rsu.getString(2) %></td>
<td><% rsu.getString(3)  %></td>
<td><% rsu.getString(4); %></td>
<td class="center"><% rsu.getString(5); %></td>
<td class="center">

<select onchange="selected_action(this.value,<%= id %>)" id="approved">
    <option >Action</option>
    <option value="approve">Approve</option>
    <option value="reject">Reject</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="btnClicked(<%= id %>)">Process</button>
</td> 
</tr>
<% 
    }
%>
```

As from above code you can See I am invoke a bootstrap popup so I want same database id in my popup when I click on Process , here I want the Id;

```
<input type="button" name="Token" class="btn btn-info" id="first-btn" value="Tokanization" onClick="btnClicked('<%= id %>')" >
```

but its giving the error that

> "Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - Tag (input) should be an empty-element tag.
>     - The local variable id may not have been    initialized"

Also I want to get same id in Servlet for further process

Thanks in Advance , Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You have erros in these lines:

```
<td><%= rsu.getString(2) %></td>
<td><% rsu.getString(3)  %></td>
<td><% rsu.getString(4); %></td>
<td class="center"><% rsu.getString(5); %></td>
```

If you put the **=** in the start of the "jsp tag" the output of the ivocation will be printed in the page. JSP compiler will generate the **<%= CODE %>** as an page.wirte() so in this case you dont use "**;**" in the end of your code.

If you dont put the **=** in the "jsp tag" the JSP compiler will include your code in the generated class. So you need to end your statements with "**;**".

You probably want something like :

```
<td><%= rsu.getString(2) %></td>
<td><%= rsu.getString(3)  %></td>
<td><%= rsu.getString(4) %></td>
<td class="center"><%= rsu.getString(5) %></td>
```